# Telemetry works on demo not on own server

Tags: demo, thingsboard, telemetry

I just started with thingsboard and have already a problem..

I'm pushing data from a database to thingsboard, which was working fine with the demo version, everything worked like a charm. Now I've set upped my own linux thingsboard server and just changed the ip-adres and authenticator of the device in the script so it matches my new server. But there is no data coming in!

The weird thing is that I can push some data from outside of a pc to thingsboard, this is visible in the telemetry data tab, but from the database directly it doesn't come in?!
Can somebode help?

Answer (score 0):

Verify you entered  IP address, Telemetry topic  is correct on your database and verify whether your database is publish data using MQTT Protocol